# PHP QR Code Class error in Linux Ubuntu

Tags: php

PHP QR Code gives the following error when executing even the most basic QR Code generation example.

> "Fatal error: Class 'QRcode' not found".

I have copied the entire PHP QR Code folder to the my `var/www` directory but still no solution.

Sample

```
 <?php

include('phpqrcode/qrlib.php');

QRcode::png('PHP QR Code :)');
?>
```

Comment: include('phpqrcode/qrlib.php'); give full file path like if windows c:// or /var/www in linux. check the class name is correct or not

Comment: @Sundar Thanks for your response, I dont understand what you mean by checking if the class name is correct. Where do I check for that? and I used the full pathname and still got the same error

Comment: If you change `include` to `require`, you'll get a fatal error if the path to your lib is wrong. As it stands, it may be producing a warning, which depending on your php.ini settings may not be being shown.

Comment: @bcmcfc Thanks. I just changed it to require and the error now is    "Failed opening required.....(include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear')" What should I change in my php.ini file?

Comment: Nothing; it just indicates that the problem is definitely the path to the file you're trying to include. It mustn't be relative to where your script is running from.

Comment: Fix the path; your 'phpqrcode' directory must not be alongside your script.

Answer (score 0):

```
//give the full path if you have linux

include('/var/www/phpqrcode/qrlib.php');

//or windows wamp or xampp

include('c://wamp/phpqrcode/qrlib.php');

//check the class is exist or not
if(class_exists('QRcode'))
{
    QRcode::png('PHP QR Code :)');

}else{

    echo 'class is not loaded properly';
}
```

Comment: Just tried it. The Class is not loading properly. How do I make it work or load properly?

Comment: change the file path like this include('/var/www/phpqrcode/qrlib.php');

Comment: I am working on Linux Ubuntu and I changed the path to what you said but it is still not working.

Comment: your folder path may like this include('/var/www/phpqrcode/qrlib.php'); check all the folders are exist or not

Answer (score 0):

This is working fine on my local Ubuntu machine (after installing phpqrcode ).

```
include('/usr/share/phpqrcode/qrlib.php');
```

If you want to keep everything in your webfolder simply copy everything from that folder to your webroot (even though it is probably better to keep it out of the webroot.)

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem until i've changed the directory's permissions to 0777.
Now for me it's working fine.